# How to use the $_ positional parameter in the fish shell?

Tags: bash, fish, positional-parameter

In **Bash**, the **positional parameter** `$_` holds the last argument in the previous command:

```
$ /home/joe> some-script foo bar
$ /home/joe> cd $_
$ /home/joe/bar>
```

The positional parameter `$_` does not seem to work in the fish shell.

Is there some way in the fish shell using which I can get the last argument in the previous command? This can be useful in cases where that argument is a really long path, which can be painful to type again.

Comment: For some people, fizsh might be an alternative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

fish uses `$_` for the currently running program: http://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#title

To get the last arg of the last command, use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>

Comment: Alt+Up is gobbled up the GNOME Terminal I'm using. Is it possible to remap this to some other keyboard shortcut?

Comment: Yes. For example, to bind "alt+." to the same thing: `bind \e. history-token-search-forward` -- see "help bind"